# Conditional clauses using Codeigniter's Active Record

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a function returning data based on the parameters passed. 
Basically, the queries change depending on the clauses.

```
if(1==$case) 
return select()->from('db')->where('x',$something)->where('y','fixed')...

else if(2==$case)
return select()->from('db')->where('x','fixed')->where('y',$something)...
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Also, is it possible to have such a  clause

```
...->where('category',*)
```

'*' to be replaced by a value or something which equates to "any".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of queries is also called "dynamic queries" because you can combine the clauses in an easy way. Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->select()
    ->from('db');
if(1==$case) {
    $query->where('x',$something)
          ->where('y','fixed')
}
elseif (2==$case){
    $query->where('x','fixed')
          ->where('y',$something)
}
....
return $query->get();
```

Answering your second question, you can use:

```
$this->db->like('category', '%');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this-

```
$where = array();

if(1==$case) 
 $where['x'] = $something;
 $where['y'] = 'fixed';

else if(2==$case)
 $where['x'] = $something;
 $where['y'] = 'fixed';

$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have simplified it like this

```
if($case == 1){
    $this->db->where('x',$something)->where('y','fixed');
}else if($case == 2){
    $this->db->where('x','fixed')->where('y',$something)
}else{
    //no where clause
}
$query  =   $this->db->get('db_table');
return $query->result();
```