# IF statement on where(codeigniter active record)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, continuous-integration

i wanna ask about active record codeigniter
is it possible to use IF statement in where active record?

```
$this->db->where("IF((month(a.create_date)) < month(now()) , d.approve_by, '') like $username" );
```

So, i want to get data approve_by but the create_date must be month before current month

i have try with mysql, and it can.

```
IF(month(a.create_date) < month(NOW()),b.approve_by,'') = 'someusername'
```

when i try to implement on active record, that not showing anything.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: You can try with this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830793/conditional-clauses-using-codeigniters-active-record OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874646/multi-conditional-where-clause-in-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks for reply, but that just for 1, ('blabla',$blabla).
for case, how to use a column from database?

Comment: you want to fectch previous months records??

Comment: yes, but now its done. i make new menu, so it divide by 2 query who running separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [Codeigniter Userguide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where)

> `$this->db->where()` accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to **FALSE**, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

`$this->db->where("IF((month(a.create_date)) < month(now()) , d.approve_by, '') like $username", NULL, FALSE);`

Answer (score 0):

We can use the **CASE** of **MYSQL** as mentioned below.

```
  $this->db->select(
     '(CASE
            WHEN orderdetails.ProductID = 0 THEN dealmaster.deal_name
            WHEN orderdetails.DealID = 0 THEN products.name
        END) as product_name'
    );
```